# How to stop crashing my app in the starting

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My app is crashing while opening the app. I have upgrade my flutter version to latest 1.9.1 .

My crash logs:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/LibraryVersion;
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.0:47)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.0:13)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.0:136)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.zza(Unknown Source:8)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzan.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.0:14)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.0:135)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.then(Unknown Source:6)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:8)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.LibraryVersion" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.communityapp-MvPXsps5u6N_ZqElCQb4zw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.communityapp-MvPXsps5u6N_ZqElCQb4zw==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.example.communityapp-MvPXsps5u6N_ZqElCQb4zw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]

Comment: Maybe add source code or something..

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: share your android>app>build.gradle file

Comment: @Dushyant Source code of your app

Answer (score 0):

check your `Android> App > build.gradle file`

check the if you are missing the strings inside the defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
 ndk {
      abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
     }
}
```

Then run `flutter clean` and try installing the app again